# WebSocket Not Working With Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, websocket4net

I am trying to use `websocket` in my `xamarin.android` application, but am unable to connect with server using `websocket class`.

Using `WebSocket4net` NuGet Package, but it's not working.

**Code**

```
WebSocket websocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + IPData[0].Trim() + ":" + IPData[1].Trim());
                     if (websocket.State != WebSocketState.None)
                     {
                         var videoIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(VideoActivity));
                         StartActivity(videoIntent);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                       .SetPositiveButton("Ok", delegate
                       {

                       })
                       .SetTitle("Connection Error")
                       .SetMessage("Not Connect to server")
                       .Show();
                     }

                 })
                 .SetTitle("IP Updated")
                 .SetMessage("IP Info Updated Successfully")
                 .Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions with following Site Demo Code:

https://websocket4net.codeplex.com/

but it's display state=0(connecting)